# How do I search a SQL List inside of python to check if the username matches a user input?

Tags: python

So I am making a login page, and I need to compare the username of an SQL list to the user input. I will also use the answer for the password. This is what I have tried and it returns false.

```
list_of_users = [('joe@gmail.com', 'qwerty'), ('jeremy', '123')]

for i in list_of_users:
    if i == 'joe@gmail.com':
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

The list_of_users is there to simulate what the SQL gives when you do cursor.fetchall() on an SQL database.
Any input would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the elements of your list are tuples of two elements. So each element has two in turn. See the definition in the official documentation of [Data Structures - Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

If you wanted to fix your code, you would then simply add a second element to the for loop:

```py
list_of_users = [('joe@gmail.com', 'qwerty'), ('jeremy', '123')]

for email, pwd in list_of_users:
    if email == 'joe@gmail.com':
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

But **this approach has a fundamental flaw for your use case**. You want to print N times 'false'? Just iterate until the mail is found and stop.

This is an example toy code:

```py
list_of_users = [('joe@gmail.com', 'qwerty'), ('jeremy', '123')]


def login(email: str, pwd: str, list_of_users: [()]) -> bool:
    for db_email, db_pwd in list_of_users:
         if (email == db_email) and (pwd == db_pwd):
             return True
    return False


print(login('jeremy', '123', list_of_users))  # True
print(login('jeremy', '456', list_of_users))  # False
```

Comment: How would I make it stop the loop? I tried to use break but the loop keeps happening.

Comment: In the code I posted, in the first example if you put the break under 'print('True') the loop stops. In the second example it is not necessary because there is a return that breaks the loop.